# Geany text editor caret block

Tags: debian, cursor, geany

I have Geany installed via apt-get on debian 8. I want to set the caret shape to be a block, but i can't find any `filetypes.common` in my `.config/geany/filedefs`. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `~/.config/geany/filedefs` only exists if you have created it, either manually or by using the menu *Tools* / *Configuration Files* / *filetypes.common* to save your configuration.

Debian's package for `geany-common` has the default settings for this file in `/usr/share/geany/filetypes.common`